# SQL Server BIDS primary key column

Tags: sql-server, bids

In BIDS I have an excel source and an OLE Database destination. However, in my OLE database I have a primary key id field which is not mapped to from my excel source. How do I create values to be inserted to my primary key id field?

I have never used BIDS before so if you need any other information, or a better explanation just let me know :)

Thanks!

Comment: Please use the `sql-server` tag (not a separate `sql` and a `server`) - also, with `sql-server`, `database` and `microsoft` are really totally redundant and don't add any additional value - skip those.

Comment: Is SQL Server your OLE DB? Put the Excel data in there first to at least create a primary key an verify the data. Then go from there to the BI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your primary key column is an `IDENTITY`, then it will populate automatically if you do not specify a value

Comment: How do I make it an IDENTITY in BIDS?

Comment: You would have to make it an IDENTITY through Management Studio or a similar solution, unless you are creating the table through BIDS...  in which case you can click the "New..." button when creating your OLEDB destination table and specify IDENTITY(1,1) (e.g. TableID INT IDENTITY(1,1))

Answer (score 0):

In your `OLEDB Destination` once you select the `table or view` to which to load the data from excel source -> move to the `column mapping tab` where you can actually **MAP** the column as per your requirement.